# PHP Carbon determine date type from string format

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have a database that contains device data and each device type may timestamp its messages differently.

Specifically, I have a string field containing this timestamp, in the following two formats:

```
2020-01-29T01:30:00.000+11:00
```

and

```
2020-01-29T00:30:01.000Z
```

I am trying to convert these strings to UTC dates, but I am  struggling with identifying the formats for Carbon. For example, this gives me "data missing" error.

```
$d = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP T', '2020-01-29T01:30:00.000+11:00', 'UTC');
```

I appreciate any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a simple typo: You have two timezone identifiers, `P   Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)` and `T    Timezone abbreviation`. Pick one, both will work:

```
$d = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', '2020-01-29T01:30:00.000Z', 'UTC');
// object(Carbon\Carbon)(
//   'date' => '2020-01-29 01:30:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 2,
//   'timezone' => 'Z'
// )

$d = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT', '2020-01-29T01:30:00.000Z', 'UTC');
// object(Carbon\Carbon)(
//   'date' => '2020-01-29 01:30:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 2,
//   'timezone' => 'Z'
// )

$d = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT', '2020-01-29T01:30:00.000+11:00', 'UTC');
// object(Carbon\Carbon)(
//   'date' => '2020-01-29 01:30:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 1,
//   'timezone' => '+11:00'
// )

$d = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', '2020-01-29T01:30:00.000+11:00', 'UTC');
// object(Carbon\Carbon)(
//   'date' => '2020-01-29 01:30:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 1,
//   'timezone' => '+11:00'
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

No format is required for these input strings. Carbon and Datetime determine this string even without format. The time zone specification "UTC" can also be omitted if a time zone is recognized in the input string. This then has priority. The time zone parameter is only effective if the entry does not contain any time zone information. The examples in @aynber's answer show that.

```
$date = new Carbon("2020-01-29T01:30:00.000+11:00");
/*
Carbon::__set_state(array(
   'date' => "2020-01-29 01:30:00",
   'timezone_type' => 1,
   'timezone' => "+11:00",
))
*/

$date = new Carbon("2020-01-29T00:30:01.000Z");
/*
Carbon::__set_state(array(
   'date' => "2020-01-29 00:30:01",
   'timezone_type' => 2,
   'timezone' => "Z",
))
*/
```

In order to recognize the format of the input, it is better to examine the input string than to try several variants of Carbon::createFromFormat.